# jquery position() is not working in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery position is not working in ie10,
Any one else is facing same issue.

```
var maillinkpos = $('#tutor-mail-link').position();
       $('#mailcountdisplay').css({'position':'absolute','left':maillinkpos.left+'112px','top':maillinkpos.top-5});
```

Please help me guys.

Comment: Have you tried `offset()`? Which does similar things but calculated differently.

Comment: yes i have tried offset() also.

Comment: `'left':maillinkpos.left+112` this would do?

Comment: maillinkpos.left+'112px' line seems strange to me try (maillinkpos.left + 112) + 'px

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove 'px' from `maillinkpos.left + '112px'`

The css method accepts numbers, similar to how `jQuery position()` method returns numbers.

It should be `maillinkpos.left + 112`

The complete code should be:

```
var maillinkpos = $('#tutor-mail-link').position();
$('#mailcountdisplay').css({
                              position : 'absolute',
                              left : maillinkpos.left + 112,
                              top : maillinkpos.top - 5
                           });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jLPn3/)

**NOTE:**

Please do check these offical sources for  more info

1. [jQuery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
2. [jQuery position](https://api.jquery.com/position/)

Comment: Also the `css()` function when passed a literal can use css hooks. No need to stringify `top`, `left`, `position` ... no need to use 'px' either since that will be 'px' by default

Comment: `maillinkpos.left+ 112px,` update it to `maillinkpos.left+ 112,`.

Comment: @Shivam Wait I will provide a Fiddle for you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47826/discussion-between-shivam-and-shaik-mahaboob-basha)

Comment: @ShaikMahaboobBasha But in IE and in Mozilla value of top is coming different.